# Why will fetch only execute when it's not in a function?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm just learning JavaScript/API call and I'm having trouble with fetch. When I call the fetch function from `myFunction` it doesn't do anything (that I can see), but if I take it out of `myFunction` it will display the error message that I expect.

I've tried to Google this but I haven't found anything that has helped me. I've added the `console.log` statements to make sure that the function is being called, and it is.

I've tried taking the `fetch` statement out of the function, and instead just putting it as a script in the html file. It works fine then. However I want to call it using the function name of a function that's in a JavaScript file and I'd like to understand why it's not working correctly right now. I think it has something to do with `fetch` not returning before the function exits, but I'm not sure.

JavaScript function:

```js
function myFunction(){

    fetch('https://sickw.com/api.php?format=html&key=SOME_KEY&imei=12908438754328705&service=999999')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        //document.write(data)
        console.log(data)
      });

    //make sure the function was called
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
}
```

html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>Ghibli App</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <form>
    <select id="carrier">
      <option value="carrier">Carrier</option>
      <option value="icloud">iCloud</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick="myFunction('carrier');">Submit</button>"
  </form>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm expecting to get a page to come up that says:

> "Error S01: Service ID is wrong!"

However the page isn't changing at all when I call the code from `myFunction()`.

Comment: You need to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: You should change your API key

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` after the page is loaded. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: I'd go as far as to say just don't use `document.write()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why you don't see anything:

The problem isn't that you're calling `fetch` from within a function, but that you're calling that function within the `onclick` of a button in a form.

When you place a `<button>` element inside of a `<form>` element, its default behavior is to submit the form (posting the results to a different web page and loading that new page in the browser). Since your form doesn't have an `action` attribute, it will just reload the current page. This reloading of the current page is causing you to not see any results.

### Fixing the *first* issue:

To prevent the form from returning, you need to call `preventDefault()` on the event passed to your function:

```
function myFunction(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('https://sickw.com/api.php?format=html&key=SOME_KEY&imei=12908438754328705&service=999999')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        //document.write(data)
        console.log(data)
      });

    //make sure the function was called
    console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
}
```

### The second issue

However because of the way you're calling this function (passing it to the `onclick` method of an HTML element) you don't have access to that event. To rectify this, you should use the `addEventListener` method like so:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

If you give the button an ID, this can be replaced with:

```
document.getElementById("button-id").addEventListener(...)
```

### The third issue

You're passing `'carrier'` directly to your function, but my guess is that you want to read the value from the `<select>` element. To do this, you should use `document.getElementById` and `.value` to read the select:

```
var carrier = document.getElementById("carrier").value;
```

Once you've done that, you can utilize `carrier` in your `fetch` request

### The fourth issue

As others have already mentioned in the comments, you should avoid calls to `document.write`. There are books written about why it's bad, but the proper answer is to use the DOM API to modify elements on the page. For instance:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = data;
document.appendChild(p);
```

### The final code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <title>Ghibli App</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <form>
    <select id="carrier">
      <option value="carrier">Carrier</option>
      <option value="icloud">iCloud</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button-id">Submit</button>"
  </form>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function myFunction(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var carrier = document.getElementById("carrier").value;
    fetch('https://sickw.com/api.php?format=html&key=SOME_KEY&imei=12908438754328705&service=999999&carrier=' + carrier)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
          var p = document.createElement("p");
          p.innerHTML = data;
          document.appendChild(p);
      });
}

document.getElementById("button-id").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! For issue #2 are you saying that I should use `addEventListener` instead of `onClick` so that I can access the event?

Comment: @SamVentocilla That's exactly right. Instead of using the `onclick` HTML attribute, if you use the `addEventListener` JavaScript method then your function will automatically be called with the event as its first parameter, which you can use prevent the event's default behavior (submitting the form). I would need to test it to be sure, but I ***think*** as a work-around you can use the HTML `onclick` attribute and have your function return `false`. In either case, using `addEventListener` is considered better practice since it keeps your code separate from your view.